# Motion Layout: How to change view visibility on last frame

Tags: android-studio, android-motionlayout

I am using motion layout in android studio to make a page that scrolls and looks kind of like Twitter. I want to set the visibility of the layout that contains the name to GONE at the very end of the animation.

Normally, if you set it to gone at the end it gradually disappears through the animation. But I want it to dissaper suddenly.

I am using motion layout and kind of understand key frames, but how do you do it with visibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to leave an answer here, in case anybody encounter this like me:

Animating `alpha` and controlling its frames does the job, but the case when you want a view to be actually `gone` from the layout, I needed to make use of `visibility` for that.

I wrote it in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587031/4538920), but keep it here for ease of read:
A background view, that should be `gone` when `alpha` is `0`, and once `alpha` is getting greater than `0` just stay `visible` all the time, but motion shouldn't animate the `visibility` all.

- Configure `KeyFrameSet` for `visibility`, so at **frame 0** `visibility` is `gone`, and starting from **frame 1** `visibility` is `visible`.
- Set required `visibility` of the background view in both `@id/start` and `@id/end` constraint sets.
- Set `visibiltyMode` as `ignore` for the background view in both `@id/start` and `@id/end` constraint sets, so motion will ignore animating this attribute for the background view.

```xml
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/transition"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="@integer/standard_duration">

       <KeyFrameSet>
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:framePosition="0"
               motion:motionTarget="@id/background">
               <CustomAttribute
                   motion:attributeName="visibility"
                   motion:customIntegerValue="8" />
           </KeyAttribute>

           <KeyAttribute
               motion:framePosition="1"
               motion:motionTarget="@id/background">
               <CustomAttribute
                   motion:attributeName="visibility"
                   motion:customIntegerValue="0" />
           </KeyAttribute>
       </KeyFrameSet>

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        ...

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:visibility="gone"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
        />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        ...

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
        />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Btw, the corresponding integer values for `visibility` are:

```
Visible = 0
Invisible = 4
Gone = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the alpha value for the 0,99 and 100th frame positions as shown below.

```
 <KeyFrameSet>

        <KeyAttribute
            android:alpha="1"
            motion:framePosition="0"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/textView" />
        <KeyAttribute
            android:alpha="1"
            motion:framePosition="99"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/textView" />
        <KeyAttribute
            android:alpha="0"
            motion:framePosition="100"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/textView" />

    </KeyFrameSet>
```

By this way, the textview will fade out from 99 to 100th frame, but it will look as it disappeared almost suddenly.

[image: gif image showing a sample animation]